# Ubuntu 20.04 server only gets IPv6 address on reboot from DHCP server, forced to release/renew to get IPv4 working every time

Tags: server, 20.04, dhcp, arm64

I'm running

Linux MYHOST 5.4.0-1022-raspi #25-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 15 13:31:49 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

My server can't route IPv4 traffic after a reboot until I connect to the IPv6 address via SSH and issue a command like: sudo dhclient -r eth0

After that manual bump I get IPv4 and seems to be able to route out.  I'm running DHCP from another box on the network running pi-hole, but I don't have this problem with any other machines on the network, just this one Ubuntu server.

Any idea why I am running into this?  I can always go static IP but I prefer to use DHCP reserved if I can get it to work consistently after a reboot with IPv4.

Regards,

JT

Comment: If you install and use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` (and read  the `man` pages) you can watch the DHCP packets go back and forth. Without that, we cannot distinguish between two potential errors: (DHCP server isn't sending IPv4 address) or (DHCP server IS sending the IPv4 address but the local system is dropping it on the floor).

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.